# Vue.js delimiters don't work in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a select form field, where the html and the value are filled in with a vue.js v-for attribute.  The HTML gets created just fine, but the value for each option remains as ${ item.id }, I'm assuming because it is in quotation marks.  Any idea how to get around this?

code:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <select>
<option v-for="item in items" value="${ item.id }">${ item.message }</option>
```

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo', id: 1 },
      { message: 'Bar', id: 2 }
    ]
  }
})
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dL9qyjdc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind it with HTML attribute, you can use `v-bind`, like follwoing:

```
<option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.id">${ item.message }</option>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dL9qyjdc/1/).